# Can I replace a fan with a lower-rated fan?

Tags: inverter, fan

I have an old RadioShack inverter / battery device that seems to have died because the fan seized up. The original fan is labeled DC 14V 0.09A. The battery in this unit puts out 16V according to my multimeter, and I read 15.37 volts at the leads that power the fan.

I can't seem to find an identical replacement online, so I am wondering if it is possible to substitute a fan rated for a lower voltage. Would a 12VDC fan work if the dimensions were the same? (This is mostly what I can find online.) What would be the down side? Shorter duty cycle?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you'll burn out the fan if you don't match the voltage. You also need to match the CFM or you might overheat whatever your cooling

Answer (score 2):

> Would a 12VDC fan work if the dimensions were the same?

Unlikely. Supplying a fan with a higher voltage than it was designed for will usually cause it to run faster than intended, and produce more heat. Both of these will significantly shorten its lifetime.

12V to 14-15V *might* be close enough that the fan will tolerate it, but I wouldn't want to risk it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always fit a simple linear regulator (7812) to drop the voltage - or even just a dropper resistor.

Say the 12V fan draws 200mA. To drop 4V, you´ll need a 20 ohm resistor. The resistor will disipate around 1W, so use a 2W, or bigger, device to be safe.